# shifting char array from left to right

Tags: c, arrays

Hi guys I am trying to code a smily face that can move from left to right. I have managed to code the smily face and print it. but I am unabel to code it so it can shift from left to right.

Here is my code til now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int charprint(char x[][8], int X, int Y)
{
   for (int i = 0 ; i<X ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<Y; j++ )
        {
            if( x[i][j]== '1')
            {
                printf(" ");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", 219);
          }

       }
       printf("\n");
   }

}
int main()
{
    char bitmap [8][8] =
    {
        {'1', 'X', 'X', '1', '1', 'X', 'X','1'},
        {'1', 'X', 'X', '1', '1', 'X', 'X','1'},
        {'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1','1'},
        {'X', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1','X'},
        {'1', 'X', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'X','1'},
        {'1', '1', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '1','1'},
        {'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1','1'},
        {'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1','1'},
    };
    charprint(bitmap, 8, 8);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: memmove() per line and than add the one character you have to move in per line

Comment: The main problem with this will be that moving graphics don't really go well together with console output. You'd need to use some OS-specific library in order for the graphic part to work.

Comment: you have to do some "terminal-magic" to get it look good => escape sequences to clear the screen after printing and some miliseconds delay with `sleep()`

Answer (score 0):

you have to consider the difference between "moving and filling with blanks after move" and "wrap around moving".

```
for each line:
  temp = wrap ? (moveleft() ? line[0] : line[7]) : '1'
  memmove(line + moveleft() ? 0 : 1, line + moveleft() ? 1 : 0, 7)
  line[moveleft() ? 7 : 0] = temp
```